# Running gazebo remotely in fuerte

Tags: ros, gazebo, ros-fuerte, ssh, remote

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,

I would like to be able to run Gazebo remotely on a computer that is faster than my own computer.  Pre-fuerte, this could be done by ssh'ing into the remote machine and running

roslaunch gazebo_worlds empty_world_no_x.launch

In fuerte, this crashes gazebo.   I have tried using the -X flag with ssh and also setting export DISPLAY=:0 with no luck.  I have also tried

roslaunch gazebo_worlds empty_world.launch gui:=false

and that also crashed trying to open a display with normal ssh.  When ssh'd with -X, it crashes with the following error:

```
X Error of failed request:  GLXUnsupportedPrivateRequest
  Major opcode of failed request:  154 
  Minor opcode of failed request:  16 (X_GLXVendorPrivate)
  Serial number of failed request:  27
  Current serial number in output stream:  28
```

Is there a way to run Gazebo remotely in Fuerte?

Thanks,

Jenny

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/42487/running-gazebo-remotely-in-fuerte/) by [jbarry](https://answers.ros.org/users/486/jbarry/) on ROS Answers with karma: 280 on 2012-08-28

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [SL Remy](https://answers.ros.org/users/1001/sl-remy/) on 2012-08-30**:
Hello! I assume that you are still ssh'ing to the same physical machine? What is the value of DISPLAY when you login to the machine directly (i.e. not over the network)? What type of graphics card are you using?

**Comment by [jbarry](https://answers.ros.org/users/486/jbarry/) on 2012-08-30**:
Yes, I'm always ssh'ing into the same physical machine.  The value of DISPLAY is :16.0 and the graphics card is nVidia 10de:0e22 (which I think is a GeForce GTX 460 although 10de:0e22 seems to be all I can actually get the computer to tell me).  Thanks!

**Comment by [hsu](https://answers.ros.org/users/91/hsu/) on 2012-08-30**:
fixes in fuerte branch.  If you checkout simulator_gazebo and compile from source, you can change `USE_HG` to true in `simulator_gazebo/gazebo/CMakeLists.txt` to try it out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

By checking out simulator_gazebo and compiling from source as suggested in the comment (although I didn't actually change USE_HG - it worked for me out of the box) I was able to get this working by launching

roslaunch gazebo_worlds empty_world.launch gui:=false

Thank you!

---

Originally posted by [jbarry](https://answers.ros.org/users/486/jbarry/) with karma: 280 on 2012-09-11

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [jbarry](https://answers.ros.org/users/486/jbarry/) on 2013-02-15**:
Update: This is still not working in /opt for me (we pull from /ros/ubuntu not shadow) but does work locally.  I did have to update gazebo-1.6 to make it work with what I think are changes in pr2_gazebo.